# Using Spring application properties in non-managed class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, environment-variables

I am using Spring Boot 3.1.2 and I have defined a custom `SecurityExpressionRoot` that handles authorization procedures.

However, I have a few values stored as environment variables, that are referenced via `application.properties`:

```
myapp.home-org=${HOME_ORG_ID}
```

They are normally used in the app by autowiring the configuration class where they are defined:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
public class EnvironmentConfig {

    /**
     * UUID of the organization users are originating from.
     */
    private UUID homeOrg;

}
```

I am looking for a way to use that variable in `SecurityExpressionRoot` as a basis for authorization decisions.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: I don't see what's holding you back from autowiring the config in your security handler. Please provide the relevant code.

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu - I have already tried autowiring it in the `SecurityExpressionRoot`, but I am getting error "Autowired members must be defined in valid Spring bean"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can statically obtain the property value by inheriting Spring Class `ApplicationContextAware` or `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`:

```
@Component
public class SpringUtil implements  BeanFactoryPostProcessor,ApplicationContextAware {  
    /**
     * Spring beanFactory
     */
    private static ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory;
    /**
     * Spring context
     */
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems")
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        SpringUtil.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems")
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        SpringUtil.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    /**
     * get {@link ApplicationContext}
     *
     * @return {@link ApplicationContext}
     */
    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }
   /**
     * get {@link ListableBeanFactory}，is {@link ConfigurableListableBeanFactory} or {@link ApplicationContextAware}
     *
     * @return {@link ListableBeanFactory}
     * @since 5.7.0
     */
    public static ListableBeanFactory getBeanFactory() {
        return null == beanFactory ? applicationContext : beanFactory;
    }
    /**
     * by class get bean
     *
     * @param <T>   Bean type
     * @param clazz Bean class
     * @return Bean
     */
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> clazz) {
        return getBeanFactory().getBean(clazz);
    }
    /**
     *  get property value
     *
     * @param  property key
     * @return property value
     */
    public static String getProperty(String key) {
        if (null == applicationContext) {
            return null;
        }
        return applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

Obtain the property:
`String value=SpringUtil.getProperty("myapp.home-org");`
or
`UUID value=SpringUtil.getBean(EnvironmentConfig.class).getHomeOrg();`

Answer (score 0):

You can define an "initializer" class that will hold the configuration needed to initialize your custom class as defined in the 3) here: https://www.baeldung.com/inject-properties-value-non-spring-class.2) would work too, but I find the initializer solution more elegant than using class loader.